# Return the value in the first non-empty cell in the column directly to the left and going upward

Tags: excel, vba, treeview, parent

I'm all new to VBA and have mostly been trying to modify code after recording macros, so it's all pretty basic and the approach might not be as elegant as some of the stuff I've seen on here. So here we go.

I have coded (by brute force) my data to be arranged like a CAD design tree view with parent products/assemblies and constituent sub-assemblies/parts.

Column E contains Level 0 top assembly Part Number
Column F contains Level 1 items Part Number
... etc all the way to ...
Column M containing Level 8 items Part Number

As an example, cell G112 contains ASSY1; cells H113 to H134 contain its constituent items.

I would like to display in a new column (i.e. Column O) the value of cell G112 (ASSY1) for each of its constituents. So O113 to O134 would show the value of G112. That would need to be applied to every single level of the assembly.

I'm not sure I'm making much sense do please have a look at the picture linked below, it speaks a thousand words. I've highlighted and colour-coded the result I would like in column O.

[image]

ADDENDUM - To clarify things:
I don't know how else to explain my request but to post a simplified version of my original picture.
[SIMPLIFIED EXCEL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0zHj.png)

.CSV available here [WeTransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a6ea2f5ffbd47170e294b33aeccc60f120200624123139/cf9f25)

Comment: Not too clear your picture correlated to your question... The values to be returned do exist in column "G:G", or in column "H:H"? The way you made the picture is completely irrelevant from this point of view. And which to be the trigger for counting start and and stop? the value in "F111"? If yes, why do you make your pseudo formula green background if nothing exists in "F134"? What green background wants to mean?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try to clarify.

Comment: Please refer to my addendum at the bottom of the original post. I have tried to simplify the table and clarify my request. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I got from somewhere else if anyone is interested:

Formula in Cell O3:

=IF(C3=0,"N/A , ALREADY TOP LEVEL",INDEX(D$2:D2,AGGREGATE(14,6,(ROW(D$2:D2)-ROW(D$2)+1)/(C$2:C2=C3-1),1)))

Copy/Paste down in every cell in column O

Answer (score 0):

A very useful tool to retrieve VBA code for determined action is the macro recorder, in the ribbon, Developer -> RecordMacro, perform you action and stop recording and then you can check the code generated for the actions you recorded. Its not the cleanest code but you can find there the lines of code for the specific actions you want. Once you step into a one concrete problem with the code you tried, you can then ask for help regarding something more concrete, more than expecting that someone will code that for you.

Anyhow if you want someone to try to solve your problem, you need to post the table with the accessible data instead of the image, for the person whoever tries to approach your problem to have the data available.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
As I have mentioned in my initial post, the record tool is what I have used to get to this point.

Comment: However, unless I'm wrong, I can't see a way to record what I'm trying to achieve here.
But as others have commented, what I thought was a clear explanation might not actually be that clear, so I'll try to clarify things a bit.
Is it possible to share a whole excel file?

Comment: How does one post a table?

Comment: You can export the data in csv format and paste some example info as plain text from the .csv, or share the file with we transfer https://wetransfer.com/